# OData for Contact Entity on ADX Portal

Tags: json, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, adxstudio-portals

I have enabled odata for contact entity. Below is the json response for it.

```
{
 "odata.metadata":"https://<myportal>.microsoftcrmportals.com/_odata/$metadata#Contacts","value":[
    {
      "contactid":"bc18d85e-55d3-e711-8134-c4346bdcfde1","fullname":"Support new","emailaddress1":"mssurfaceplussupport@abc.com","parentcustomerid":null,"telephone1":null,"list-id":"64985f31-0fdf-e711-812d-c4346bdd8041","view-id":"00000000-0000-0000-00aa-000010001004","entity-permissions-enabled":null
    }
  ]
}
```

In this json response, I am getting values of some fields like fullname, emailaddress1 etc. etc.

I also want values of other fields like owner, ownerid etc.

Also, How can I anable odata for User, Team, Business Unit entities.

I am calling this json from adx portal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get 'ownerid' column from CRM database of type \`owner\` using Web API approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062099/how-to-get-ownerid-column-from-crm-database-of-type-owner-using-web-api-appr)

Comment: Hi, 

I asked this question on 20 Dec. So, this question is not duplicate of the question which is asked two days before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want value in JSON that data must be present on your view for which you want odata.

Also, Odata is obsolete so you can use liquid templates. It is an easy and good way to get the JSON response of your entities and custom entities.