# How to get 'ownerid' column from CRM database of type `owner` using Web API approach?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I'm using **Microsoft dynamics 365 - on premises** of my client. Here, I am facing an issue in accessing one of the fields - `ownerid` of type `owner`.

I am using Web API approach to access the CRM data. When I hit the query in URL, it brings all the data except `ownerid` column.

It's `field type` is: `Simple`

Has anyone faced the same issue with WebAPI query approach?

URL Query:

```
https://baseURL/moves?$select=moveid,ownerid,movenumber&$filter=movenumber%20eq%20%27236659%27
```

Output:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://baseURL/$metadata#moves(moveid,ownerid,movenumber)","value":[
    {
      "@odata.etag":"W/\"37655223\"","moveid":"4583b2fe-83d9-e611-80c7-369e029457bb","movenumber":"236659"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @ArunVinoth, updated question as per your suggestion with tried approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ownerid is a lookup, so you need to expand it first by using `$expand` query parameter, to be included in the response.

```
https://baseURL/moves?$expand=ownerid&$select=moveid,ownerid,movenumber&$filter=movenumber%20eq%20%27236659%27
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value